# Implementing a multi-input model in Keras, each with a different sample sizes each (different batch sizes each)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-processing, keras

I am currently trying to implement a multi-input model in Keras. The input consists of multiple batches, and each includes different samples, but I get a 'different samples'-error. My implementation looks like this:

The model site looks as follows:

```
for s in range(NUM_STREAMS):
    inp.append(Input(shape=(16,8)))
...
```

The site where the error occurs:

```
history = model.train_on_batch(
                x=[x for x in X_batch],
                y=[y for y in y_batch]
            )
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of
samples. Got array shapes: [(6, 16, 8), (7, 16, 8), (6, 16, 8), (6, 16, 8)]
```

The abstract model architecture looks as follow:

[image: Multiple input, Multiple output]

Comment: You should provide enough details such as the model structure. What is the form of data and labels etc. However, I don't think Keras will be a very good tool for such networks. You can try PyTorch that have dynamic computational graphs. I am not saying it is not possible in Keras, but it may be relatively difficult.

Comment: @DaveTheAI How did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hey @N.IT, its 1.5 years ago, but I remember I could just append random filler values and ignore the output again. (i.e. if the input is (6, 6, 7, 6), I append some random input such that it is (7, 7, 7, 7) and just ignore the very last items where it was appended)

Comment: Just to add some context, see also https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11993, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11548, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/12004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, when faced with a similar problem, I rewrote my model in tensorflow, as their computational graphs are not constrained to keeping a batch size dimension constant.